# Sphinx search and supervisors

Tags: search, sphinx, supervisord

I am using supervisord to control my processes. Supervisord requires that the programs it runs [does not daemonize](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html#nondaemonizing-of-subprocesses).

I solve this by having a stanza like:

```
[program:sphinx_search]
command=searchd -c /usr/local/etc/sphinx.conf --nodetach
...
...
```

But the sphinx search documentation states that the nodetach option should be used only for debugging:

> `--nodetach` switch (Linux only)
>   tells searchd not to detach into background. This will also cause log entry to be printed out to console. Query processing operates as usual. This is a debugging option.

Wondering how others have solved this problem.

Comment: The way I did it above i.e. using the --nodetach option works fine. Just wondering if it were the right way to do it.

Comment: Its intended for debugging, but there doesnt seem to be any reason not to use it.

Comment: "This is a debugging option." does not mean "...should be used only for debugging". It's perfectly fine to use.